# Copying materials doesn't work

Tags: materials

Based on a tutorial I should be able to copy material if I select all the objects, making sure that the object I'm copying from is active. And then right clicking on the material and selecting "Copy to selected".

There's two places where I can click on the material. In one of them "Copy to selected" can be clicked but does nothing.
In the other it's not even clickable.

Is this an error or am I just dumb?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I make a copy of a material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43839/3710)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution below, and no you are not, a little explanation first:

Regarding the menus you had there, the material index might be possible to copy to other objects, but i'm honestly not sure what that would do. The menu from the name, well the other objects would not accept the string value, as objects can not have the same name.

While right clicking on the Material in the list or the name underneath gives the option to "Copy to Selected", you missed another place that does the trick.

**Solution:**

[image: the right place to copy material to selected]

The little "v" under the "-" on the right side opens the menu concerning the material with the function you want "Copy Material to Selected".

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

My sanity is saved for another day :)